# How to increase the array block i want to manipulate

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop

so my assignment is as follows:

"Write a program that reads in a list of numbers from an input text file called input.txt. For each number read, your program should determine and print out whether or not that number is abundant."

input.txt = 
[image]

i have the code down and i think i finally figured out how to find and sum all the divisors to check if a number is abundant or not but the question i have is how do i go to the next array block to check the next number? Now it is checking **"15"** which is the first number to check(the **5** tells the program how many numbers it needs to check) but how do i get it to check the next number **3** and so on?

thank you!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 100

int main(){

FILE *ifp;
int cases;
int i;
int j;
int counter = 1;
int dividen =1;
int listArray[SIZE];
int sum = 0;

ifp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
fscanf(ifp,"%d", &cases);

for(i=0;i<cases;i++){
 fscanf(ifp,"%d",&listArray[i]);
 printf("%d\n", listArray[i]);}


while(listArray[0] > counter){
 if(listArray[0] % dividen == 0){
 sum = sum+dividen;
 dividen++;
 counter++;}
 else{
 dividen++;
 counter++;}
 }

if(listArray[0] > sum)
      printf("\n%d is not an abundant number\n",listArray[0]);

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the code that checks abundance into the same loop where you store into `listArray`, or write another loop right after it that works on each element of `listArray`.

A good solution to problems like this in general is something like:

```
static const int TO_READ = 3; // For example.
FILE* file = open_input_file();
variable foo, bar, baz;
while ( TO_READ == fscanf( file, format, &foo, &bar, &baz )) {
  do_stuff_with( foo, bar, baz );
}
```